# Restrict clickable area of a checkbox control in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a custom checkbox control and inherited the class from System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox.I set the dock property of this control as Top. I added some text to the control. The control has some empty space. Now if click on the empty space, this check box is working. I need to restrict the empty space from clickable area.

The below is what i tried,

```
public class MyCheckBox : System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
{
    private int boxWidth = 15;

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        Point mouseLocation = this.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
        if (mouseLocation.X > boxWidth)
            return;

        base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```

This is working fine when clicking on the box of the checkbox control. But i need to add the text area too to the clickable area.

Comment: share whatever you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your users to play "checkbox sniper" (the clickable area is large for a reason), you can consider placing just a checkbox without text, resizing it to the smallest possible size and display the text using a separate label.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the empty area to be "clickable", then don't dock it to the top of the form. If you dock a standard `CheckBox` at the top, you'll see the same effect. The hit area becomes the entire width of the form.

Just place the control at the top of the screen with `Dock` set to `None`.

Or dock a `Panel` to the top of the screen, then place your custom `CheckBox` control inside that.

Comment: Thank you for writing Grant,

Comment: The text may change dynamically and so the length too. So the size cannot be set to a fixed one. That's why i set the dock property to Top.